# Replace numbers in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I want to replace specific numbers with exact match in comma separeted values in Mysql table with query column.

For example value is: `0,40,140,240,340,440`
and now i want to replace 40 with 50 then result shall be: `0,50,140,240,340,440`

Please note data type in that perticular column is 'Text'.

Comment: This task is hard, because RDBMSs are meant to store a single value in a column. Once this rule is violated (i.e. the data is not normalized), you are into all kinds of trouble. Make a separate table with a foreign key to the current table, and store the individual numbers in that new table, one number per column.

Comment: In my failed answer below, I tried to do a regex replace of the number 40 in the string, and it did not work.  Really, just break those CSV numbers across separate rows and your life will become much easier.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen
I appriciate your suggestion but i've to create script for from number and to number so i can't replace using CSV

Comment: MySQL isn't the best place to be doing this.  You will probably have to create a UDF for this or find a 3rd party library.  I don't think this is possible using MySQL's base text functions.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen
you can suggest me UDF for the same

Comment: @Harddy I don't know of one per se.  You may have to write a function from scratch.  But it would be much easier to handle this in a tool like Java, C#, Perl, etc.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen
I do understand as i'm trying to do it with PHP but issue is that i'm having thousands of rows and it will take much time to execute and also load on server

Comment: Well it's going to be a big load on MySQL as well...databases weren't really designed with this sort of operation in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comments above that this isn't a good way to store this data, but I know that sometimes business requirements require us to do things that are less than optimal.  So in that spirit, you could write SQL that would:

1. add commas to the beginning and end of the string
2. replace ',40,' with ',50,'
3. remove the leading and trailing commas

Doing steps one and three would allow you to always assume that all entries start and end with commas so that you don't accidentally change 140 to 150 or 400 to 500.  So that would look something like this:

```
SUBSTRING(REPLACE(',' + test + ',', ',40,', ',50,'), 2, LEN(test))
```

When I tried that on your string, the result was "0,50,140,240,340,440".

Comment: Thanks Man for the this trick but it's not working for me. Please guide me if i'm doing something wrong. Here's my query 

`UPDATE <table> set <field> = SUBSTRING(REPLACE(',' + <field> + ',', ',40,', ',50,'), 2, LENGTH(<field>) where id=1`

Comment: Above is updaring with blank

Comment: Are you saying your result is an empty string?  Can you tell me the value of <field> where id=1 (the original value)?

Comment: The problem could possibly be from a missing close parenthesis after "LENGTH(<field>)".  I'm using Microsoft SQL Server, so the syntax might be slightly different, but I just got it to work like this:

    CREATE TABLE test (id INT, field VARCHAR(100));

    INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, '0,40,140,240,340,440');

    UPDATE test set field = SUBSTRING(REPLACE(',' + field + ',', ',40,', ',50,'), 2, LEN(field)) where id=1;

    SELECT * FROM test;

    drop TABLE test;

(I'm sorry, this isn't formatting very nicely in the comment)

Comment: I'm using Mysql and query is as below 
`UPDATE book set BU_IDS = SUBSTRING(REPLACE(',' + BU_IDS + ',', ',40,', ',50,'), 2, LENGTH(BU_IDS)) where id=1`

Comment: And what is the value of BU_IDS where id=1?  Is it the value you gave in the original question?

Comment: Yes My friend
when it will update then value will be again in same format as comma separeted as mentioned in question 
`0,50,140,240,340,440`

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Did I solve your problem?

Comment: It's okay my friend :)
I wrote PHP script for the same But your suggestion was awesome